# iCloud Keychain out of sync after Mac user password change

Tags: macos, icloud, mojave, password, keychain

on my macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132), where I'm logged in with my iCloud account, if I perform a domain Mac user password change (from System Preferences) then the iCloud Keychain sync will be turned off. If I go to iCloud prefs I can re-enable iCloud Keychain, but it won't sync anymore with the ones I've on my iDevices.

Any hint about it?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Mariano, welcome to Ask Different. I'm hit by this bug every time I change my password on my work Mac. Logging out and in to iCloud has always helped. I'd recommend that you wait a minute or so before logging in back again. When you log out, choose to keep a copy of contacts and calendar events. After logging in, give your Mac a few minutes for duplicate entries to be deleted and sync to finish.

Comment: Thanks @jaume for the answer, I've already tried such solution but it will every time delete documents I share on iCloud. Probably I found a good workaround: before to perform a password change I disable the iCloud Keychain (keeping a local copy), then I change password, after logging in again with the new password I re-enable the iCloud Keychain. It seems to work without any need to logout from iCloud and/or loose data. Tell me if it works for you as well

Comment: Nice workaround, I'l try it next time I have to change my password. Could you add your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted so that the question appears as answered? Thanks!

Comment: @Mariano, have you tried rebooting after changing pass? This would force icloud processes to shutdown and reconnect from zero. (i know it was not supposed to happen and reboot is not necessary, but to validate if it is some kind of bug which is keeping old settings, a reboot is valid to help debug the behaviour)

Comment: Hi @Prado, yes I tried to just reboot and also to force `bird` daemon to restart, with no lucky :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I found an acceptable workaround:

- disable the iCloud Keychain (keeping a local copy)
- change password,
- log out and log in again into your User account
- re-enable the iCloud Keychain

It seems to work with any need to log out from iCloud and/or loose data.